Using health in Flutter: ^ 11.1.1 compiling with Xcode error Undefined symbol:___ gxx_personality_v0
Setting ENV ['SWIFT_VERSION ']='5.1' in Podifile and adding '- lc+' to Other Linker Flags still doesn't work. It should be related to my other SDK, and I don't know how to find this problem

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
